# Misplaced sub-shell in bash

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting, ksh

I'm having trouble with an unfortunate mis-feature in bash, illustrated by this function:

```
trying ()
{
    res=0;
    echo $res;
    cat some_text_file | while read op rpt rec; do
        res=1;
        echo $res;
    done;
    echo $res
}
```

What i had expected was that the last `echo $res` would print `1` - however, it prints `0`. The reason is that the loop starting with `cat some_text_file | while read op rpt rec; do` runs in a sub-shell, whereas in ksh it doesn't.

A work-around for this simple case would be:

```
trying ()
{
    res=0;
    echo $res;
    while read op rpt rec; do
        res=1;
        echo $res;
    done < some_text_file;
    echo $res
}
```

However, in most cases it would be more like `cat some_file | awk '{...}' | while read ...`, and I'd really like to not create a temporary file just for this; it just ought to work.

Unfortunately I have work with bash on my servers, otherwise it would be ksh everywhere. So, are there any good ways around this?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few workarounds:

1. You can activate `shopt -s lastpipe` to get the ksh-like behavior. This only works where job control is disabled – i.e. you can always use this option in standalone scripts, but while using an interactive shell it will only affect pipes inside `(`subshells`)`.
2. If the variables only need to be short-lived (and there isn't anything besides the 'while' loop which would need to read stdin), you can pipe to a *command list*:

   ```
   cat some_file | awk '{...}' | {
       res=0
       echo $res
       while read op rpt rec; do
           res=1
           echo $res
       done
       echo $res
   }
   ```
3. You can use bash's *process substitution* operator `<(...)` to read from a subshell as if it were a named file, including redirecting it to a 'while' loop:

   ```
   res=0
   echo $res
   while read op rpt rec; do
       res=1
       echo $res
   done < <(cat some_file | awk '{...}')
   echo $res
   ```
4. You're already using awk...

   ```
   cat some_file | awk '{...}' | awk '
      BEGIN { res = 0 }
      { res = 1 }
      END { print res }
   '
   ```